# numpy fromstring empty string separator

Tags: python, string, numpy

When I call:

```
np.fromstring('3 3 3 0', sep=' ')
```

it returns

```
array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  0.])
```

Since by default, `sep=''`, I would expect the following call to return the same result:

```
np.fromstring('3330')
```

However it raises

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Why is this? What's the most pythonic way of getting `array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  0.])` from `'3330'`?

Comment: The documentation says this about the `sep` keyword: "If not provided or, equivalently, the empty string, the data will be interpreted as binary data."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
In [11]: np.fromiter('3300', dtype=np.float64)
Out[11]: array([ 3.,  3.,  0.,  0.])

In [12]: np.fromiter('3300', dtype=np.float64, count=4)  # count=len(..)
Out[12]: array([ 3.,  3.,  0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

`list('3330')` turns the string into a 4 element list of chars; with the correct dtype, `np.array` will convert those strings to numbers:

```
In [48]: np.array(list('3330'),dtype=float)
Out[48]: array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  0.])
```

The `fromiter` solution is faster, but that's one more function to remember.